# Regex match last square brackets in SQL Script SSMS

Tags: regex, ssms, pcre

I am trying to perform a regex match in SQL Server Management Studio 2017 to then do a replace on part of a SQL script that looks as follows:

```
,ISNULL([Gt 01 To 02 Weeks SUM 1],0) AS [Gt 01 To 02 Weeks SUM]
,ISNULL([Gt 02 To 03 Weeks SUM 1],0) AS [Gt 02 To 03 Weeks SUM]
```

I want to match on the last `[` and `]` e.g. using example line `[`Gt 02 To 03 Weeks SUM`]`; so I can the replace `[|]` with `'`

I tried

```
(?<=\sAS\s).*(\[)Gt|SUM(\])
```

And this gives:

[image]

which is full matches rather than the group matches I wish to replace

I then tried:

```
(?<=\sAS\s).*?(\[)|(?<=\sAS\s)?(\])
```

But this matches one too many (i.e. it matches on the penultimate `]` as well.

[image]

I tried a few other things to no avail.

Behaviour seems to match as per using PCRE PHP on regex 101. Example: [here](https://regex101.com/r/TryCYX/1/) so I added that tag but I am not experienced enough in this domain to know if that is valid.

How do I change this regex please to only match on the last brackets?

Comment: Perhaps use 2 capturing groups with a replacement of `$1'$2'` for example  `(AS )\[([^\]]+)\]` See https://regex101.com/r/8fmh11/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use 2 capturing groups and match the `[` and `]` so that they can be replaced with `'`

```
(AS )\[([^\]]+)\]
```

- `(AS )` Capture **group 1** Match `AS`
- `\[` Match `[`
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[^\]]+` Negated character class, match any char 1+ times except `]`
- `)` Close group
- `\]` Match `]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8fmh11/1)

In the replacement use the 2 capturing groups

```
$1'$2'
```